# Django Admin save_model() creating duplicate objects

Tags: django, django-admin

While clicking on save button multiple times. Multiple entries are getting created in db. How can i put a check there.

Comment: Share your model and modeladmin...

Comment: One helpful thing  might be model meta unique_together https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 0):

When overriding `ModelAdmin.save_model()` and `ModelAdmin.delete_model()`, your code must save/delete the object. They aren’t meant for veto purposes, rather they allow you to perform extra operations. So you should handle update action. This is example I try to fix this problem, maybe helpful with you.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # check for update action
        if obj.id is not None:
            obj.save()
        else: # check for create, delete action
            id_li = list(EquipmentCategory.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))
            if len(id_li) > 0:
                max_id = max(id_li)
            else:
                max_id=0
            obj.id = max_id+1
            obj.save()
            super(EquipmentCategoryAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```